# Connecting c# application form to text file using app.config file

Tags: c#, winforms, text-files, app-config

I am connecting my c# application form with text file. But I dn't want it to be hard-coded.
So far my code in the file is given below. I dn't want to display the file name and path file. I rather want it to put in app.config file and use it from app.config filw. Can you tell me which changes i have to do in this file and app.config file :

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    string sqlConnectionString = @"C:\Jaspreet_Files\LoadOrgInPortal.txt";

        var fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Jaspreet_Files\LoadOrgInPortal.txt");


        fileContents = fileContents.Replace("{param_1}", textBox1.Text.ToString());
        fileContents = fileContents.Replace("{param_2}", textBox2.Text.ToString());
        fileContents = fileContents.Replace("{param_3}", textBox3.Text.ToString());
        fileContents = fileContents.Replace("{param_4}", textBox4.Text.ToString());
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Jaspreet_Files\NewLoadOrgInPortal.txt", fileContents);

        Application.Exit();

    }
```

And my app.config file is empty at the moment.I mean I didn't do any coding there yet.

Comment: and your app.config is?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> <configuration> </configuration>

Comment: I really need help with this. Thanks, waiting for reply

Comment: Is you question, "How can I read the filename from the app.config file?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Settings are very straight forward.

Add your properties to your App.Config app settings, e.g.

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="sqlConnectionString" value="C:\Jaspreet_Files\LoadOrgInPortal.txt" />
  </appSettings>
```

..and read them, e.g.

```
   var sqlConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["sqlConnectionString"];
```

Comment: I like this quicker way, unless a finer control is required. I have never come across a situation where someone needed a finer control.

Comment: Thanks George. I really appreciate your help

Comment: It would be even more appropriate to use the `<connectionStrings>` section in `app.config` which is intended for **exactly** this use case - storing connection strings...

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Configuration;
...
...
...

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AppSettingsReader reader = new AppSettingsReader();
    string txtFilePath  = (string)reader.GetValue("txtFilePath", typeof(string));

    //string sqlConnectionString = @"C:\Jaspreet_Files\LoadOrgInPortal.txt";
    string sqlConnectionString = txtFilePath;

    //var fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Jaspreet_Files\LoadOrgInPortal.txt");
    var fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(txtFilePath);


    fileContents = fileContents.Replace("{param_1}", textBox1.Text.ToString());
    fileContents = fileContents.Replace("{param_2}", textBox2.Text.ToString());
    fileContents = fileContents.Replace("{param_3}", textBox3.Text.ToString());
    fileContents = fileContents.Replace("{param_4}", textBox4.Text.ToString());
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Jaspreet_Files\NewLoadOrgInPortal.txt", fileContents);

    Application.Exit();

}
```

Comment: Is there any way that I dn't have to display the file path in code. Can I display only in app.config file?

Comment: Edited code to pick file path from config.

Comment: You can do the same for `NewLoadOrgInPortal.txt`. Creating a new key in app.config etc. Just follow whatever has been done for original file.

Comment: Yeah I did the same for NewLoadOrgInPortal.txt. Thanks Abhinav